# Swift MacOS NSAnimationContext not following its duration

Tags: swift, macos, nsanimationcontext

I have a very simple animation which is moving a view throughout the main view like this:

```
NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ (_) in
    NSAnimationContext.current.duration = 50.0
    viewTOModify.frame.origin.x = -20
}) {
    print("finished")
}
```

This issue I have with this is that the movement is instantaneous and there is not the duration I set. Thanks for the help in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the view's `.animator()` method like this:

```
NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ (_) in
    NSAnimationContext.current.duration = 50.0
    viewTOModify.animator().frame.origin.x = -20
}) {
    print("finished")
}
```

If you don't want to use `.animator()` you have to set `.allowsImplicitAnimation` like this:

```
NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ (_) in
    NSAnimationContext.current.duration = 50.0
    NSAnimationContext.current.allowsImplicitAnimation = true
    viewTOModify.frame.origin.x = -20
}) {
    print("finished")
}
```